# update array elements with try catch

Tags: jq

I'm trying to update large complexe json files and exit with detailled error message when detecting incoherent data (with jq 1.6).

I started to use functions and try/catch to produce a kind of java stacktrace containing input data from each level => easy, thank you JQ

But when I started to update array elements (using |=), I didn't find the solution

Here is a very simple example :

```
echo '{"array": [{"foo":"bar"}]}' | jq -c '.array[] |= try . catch (.)'
output : {"array":[{"__jq":0}]}
```

Do I made a mistake ? Is it a normal behaviour ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try-catch isn't really an expression, it yields no meaningful value, it merely executes some expression:

[try-catch](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#try-catch)

> Errors can be caught by using try EXP catch EXP. **The first expression is executed, and if it fails then the second is executed with the error message.** The output of the handler, if any, is output as if it had been the output of the expression to try.

emphasis mine.

So it would be wrong to use the value, you should perform the assignment within the try expression.

```
$ echo '{"array": [{"foo":"bar"}]}' | jq -c 'try (.array[] |= .) catch (.)'
```

Comment: `try ... catch ...` is a compound expression, and yields a value just like any other jq filter.  Please see my response to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled upon a bug in jq 1.6. Using jq 1.5, one obtains the correct output:

```
{"array":[{"foo":"bar"}]}
```

However, the expression `.array[] |= try . catch (.)` is not one would ever use in practice, because if .array is a JSON array or JSON object, it just says: do nothing.

To understand `try ... catch ...`, it might help to consider this example:

```
$ jq -n 'try error("abc") catch ("The error message was " + .)'
"The error message was abc"
```